# How to create Data file for storing input data such as employee info

Tags: java, java-io

guys i saw these couple of codes while i was browsing on the net. when i read the the whole content it says that these codes are for creating a data file for storing an inputs such as Employee information or registered accounts etc. can anyone please give me an example for this?

```
backupRecords();
outputstream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.dat"));
reWriteRecords(outputstream);
inputstream = new DataInputStream(new FileOutputStream("temp.dat"));
```

Comment: OK... give us some context.  Please post the link to the code.

Comment: You sure you didn't confuse it with [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)?

Comment: Link? ....................................

Comment: @fabian - Yes!  I sussed out another disguised homework copypasta request!

Comment: the link that Mr. fabian sent is exactly the same thing i saw earlier

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer assuming that you wanted to know hot the contents of the input file look like.

The easy answer would be something like this:

data.txt:

```
Yuri;Gagarin;Russia;52;Male
Booch;Gary;USA;40;Male
Randy;Orton;USA;52;Male
Anna;Tereshkova;Russia;40;Female
Maria;Sharapova;Russia;32;Female
```

Notice the delimiter ';'. The java code after opening the file for reading, reads the contents of the file and would be written under the assumption that each occurrence of the delimiter ';' gives a piece of information. For example, FirstName or LastName or Country or Age or Gender.

The better solution for reading data is xml.

data.xml:

```
<PersonInfo>
<FirstName>Yuri</FirstName>
<LastName>Gagarin</LastName>
<Country>Russia</Country>
<Age>52</Age>
<Gender>Male</Gender>

....
</PersonInfo>
```

Comment: Have an upvote for useful info and NOT providing the OP with example code:)

Comment: so sir pavan .. can you please give me an example program for this?, i'm really interested with this, because it might come in handy to me someday especially if i'm going to make a register program for an app.

Comment: hmm,, ok sir,, thanks anyway for the answer :)